# Getting javascript to alert the user from this regex test

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the following regex test on a users input:

```
function validate_form() {

return /^[a-fA-F0-9]+$/.test(document.form.input.value);

}
```

I the users input failed to meet the criteria, then how would i get an alert put in this code to inform them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the `return` statement with:

```
var isValid = /^[a-fA-F0-9]+$/.test(document.form.input.value);
if (!isValid) alert("Your value was invalid.");
return isValid;
```

Alternatively, you could keep your validation function as above, and do:

```
if (!validate_form()) alert("Your value was invalid.");
```

If you want to show the error message in the document itself, then you could do something like, and replace `alert()` above with `error()`:

```
function error(message) {
  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = message;
}
```

This assumes that you have an element in your HTML with `id="error"` e.g.:

```
<div id="error"></div>
```

Comment: This answer works for me, by the way i had to take out the second closing bracket in the variable. However when i do document.write to put the error message on the page instead of a alert in form of a pop up, it clears everything apart from the error message. any suggestions?

Comment: I would advise against using `document.write` for this reason.  It will always clear the page except in the rare case when you're using it at page load time.  You're better off using something like: `document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Your value was invalid.";`.  I'll update my answer with a longer example.

Answer (score 1):

```
function validate_form() {

   var alphanumeric = /^[a-fA-F0-9]+$/.test(document.form.input.value);
   if(!alphanumeric){ alert("Silly human, you cannot use punctuation here!"); }
   return alphanumeric;

}
```

Comment: @Will_Martin I like this answer and it works, however, when i change alert to write, so that its just displays message on screen without pop up box then it doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use `document.write()` to output the message. That only works at the initial page load. Try using something like `document.getElementById("whatever").innerHTML = "hi";` -- though if you're using jQuery it would be `$("#whatever").html("hi");`. Other frameworks (Prototype, etc) have their own methods for writing HTML to the document. Check your framework's API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate_form() {

return (/^[a-fA-F0-9]+$/.test(document.form.input.value)) ? "":alert("There is a problem with your input");

}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9qVU/

Comment: I like how example user input appears hard-coded in the function. The user's probably a real hacker.

Comment: Its just to test.  Since he didn't post the html.